# React-Router <Link> component doesn't get activeStyle applied, after connecting redux-store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I recently started learning React / Redux and right now I'm trying to build a small single page application.

Lately I ran into an issue that I did't understand and couldn't fix.

Let me show you the code:

### index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'

import App from './components/App'
import Home from './components/Home'
import About from './components/About'

const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  return state
}

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    reducer,
    routing: routerReducer
  })
)

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, store)

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>

        <Route path='about' component={About}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Basically this is the example from the to [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) GitHub page (scroll down to the section *Tutorial*) - the only difference is, that I am using a **hashHistory**.

### App.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

import Navigation from './Navigation'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation/>

        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
}
```

### Navigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router'

export default class Navigation extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul role='nav'>
        <li><IndexLink to='/' activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>Home</IndexLink></li>
        <li><Link to='/about' activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>About</Link></li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

The Home and About components are just rendering a <h1> Headline to visualize the state of the SPA.

So far, everything works fine as you would expect it! When the user clicks the *About* link, the URL changes accordingly and the link turns red (because of the activeStyle property).

But here comes my problem (thanks for still reading this btw):

I want to wrap my <Navigation> component via **react-redux** connect(). So this is my new version

### Navigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router'

class Navigation extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul role='nav'>
        <li><IndexLink to='/' activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>Home</IndexLink></li>
        <li><Link to='/about' activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>About</Link></li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

const NavigationContainer = connect()(Navigation)

export default NavigationContainer
```

But now the activeStyle feature seems to be broken... When I navigate through my app, the currently active link does not change its color anymore.

I really tried to solve this issue for hours :( Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

react-redux's connect() preventing Navigation , and subsequently links, from rerendering on a location state change.

If you add `console.log("Navigation render")` in Navigation's render , you will see that after you add connect() func, component doesnt re-render on a location state change.

---

**There are ways to avoid it**

**1.way:** in order to re-render Navigation comp on location change, you can add prop , something like that `location={this.props.location}`

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation location={this.props.location}/>

        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

**2.way:** add `{pure:false}` to connect().  **[DOCS LINK](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux)**

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions, null, { pure: false })(Navigation);
```

---

**3.way:** This is fixed in React Router 3.0.0-alpha.1 and newer.

Comment: I had a similar problem with MobX. react-router@3.0.0-alpha.3 seems to work, while 2.x didn't.

Comment: This seriously needs to be documented better with React-Router. At first one might not think this was theirs to correct with Redux's Connect() being the culprit.  But apparently they did with the changes in the 3.0.0-alpha.x.  I was going nuts until I stumbled upon this from @ultro .

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for ages! Glad to know it's fixed in 3. I'm using a rubbish timeout function to forceUpdate() until I upgrade.